# PHP - Sanitize string removes numbers

Tags: php, sanitization

I am attempting to define allowed characters in an array, and then sanitize strings based on this array. The below code works pretty good except that it removes chars 0-9 too!

Could someone please explain why this is?

Code:

```
    <?php

//Allowed characters within user data:
$symbols = array();
$symbols += range('a', 'z');
$symbols += range('A', 'Z');
$symbols += range('0', '9');
array_push($symbols,' ','-'); // Allow spaces and hyphens.

//----test 1

//data to test.
$someString = "07mm04dd1776yyyy";

//sanatize
$someString = trim(preg_replace("/[^" . preg_quote(implode('',$symbols), '/') . "]/i", "", $someString));

echo "$someString\n";

//----test 2
$someString = "Another-07/04/1776-test-!@#$%^&*()[]\\;',./\"[]|;\"<>?";

//sanatize
$someString = trim(preg_replace("/[^" . preg_quote(implode('',$symbols), '/') . "]/i", "", $someString));

echo "$someString\n";

?>
```

Output:

```
mmddyyyy
Another--test-
```

Sidenote (edit): This is used in conjunction with a database but it goes beyond the DB, the data in the DB is used to write powershell scripts which import users into Active Directory, and many characters are not allowed, plus the old system only allowed these characters also.

Thank you in advance,
Wayne

Comment: Sidenote: Does this have anything to do with a database by any chance? If so, you don't need all that. You can use a prepared statement.

Comment: It does, but it goes beyond the DB, the data in the DB is used to write powershell scripts which import users into Active Directory, and many characters are not allowed, plus the old system only allowed these characters also.

Comment: Ok. I added your comment to your question as an edit if you don't mind. It might have a bearing on the outcome of possible answers.

Comment: I suspect it's an issue with the way you're adding the ranges to the database - if you put the `$symbols += range('0', '9');` line first, it will add numbers to the array, but as it is, `$symbols` doesn't include numbers if you print it out. In neither case does it seem to include the uppercase letters.

Comment: @andrewsi Wow, you are correct. So why are the upper case letters left if they are not included in the $symbols array? Why aren't the numbers being added to the array?

Comment: @WayneWorkman - I've no idea; I didn't even know that you could use + to append to an array, so I suspect that that might be the issue. Could you perhaps use `array_push` instead?

Comment: The reason the upper characters remained is due to the `/i` flag in your regular expressions making it case insensitive.

Comment: @fyrye I tested, you're correct. I modified the answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going off of what @andrewsi said with the allowed chars not being added to the array, I figured out how to add them properly. The below code shows they are added, and the outputs of the test strings.

There's probably a better way to do this, so I added it to the community wiki.

```
<?php

//Allowed characters within user data:
$symbols = array();
array_push($symbols,implode("",range('0', '9')));
array_push($symbols,implode("",range('a', 'z')));
array_push($symbols,implode("",range('A', 'Z')));
array_push($symbols,' ','-'); // Allow spaces and hyphens.

print_r($symbols);
echo "\n";

//----test 1

//data to test.
$someString = "07mm04dd1776yyyy";

//sanatize
$someString = trim(preg_replace("/[^" . preg_quote(implode('',$symbols), '/') . "]/", "", $someString));

echo "$someString\n";

//----test 2
$someString = "Another-07/04/1776-test-!@#$%^&*()[]\\;',./\"[]|;\"<>?";

//sanatize
$someString = trim(preg_replace("/[^" . preg_quote(implode('',$symbols), '/') . "]/", "", $someString));

echo "$someString\n";

?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0123456789
    [1] => abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
    [2] => ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
    [3] =>  
    [4] => -
)

07mm04dd1776yyyy
Another-07041776-test-
```

Comment: Am curious why you're not using metacharacters instead like `preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z\d- ]/', '');` this will replace any special characters other than hyphen and spaces. Example: http://ideone.com/ngOrjQ I added some other special characters as well. Allso you don't need to use `array_push`, just simply use `$array[] = $value` like so: http://ideone.com/R9VK00

Comment: @fyrye Because I'm still learning php, and because I don't understand all the characters you put in that preg_replace statement you posted, and the way I wrote it above makes sense to me and is easy to understand for me.

Comment: The metacharacters can be looked up and are fairly standard for all programming languages that use regular expressions. https://www.hscripts.com/tutorials/regular-expression/metacharacter-list.php. So the expression I wrote `[^]` means patterns that do not match, `a-z` are lowercase characters  a through z,  `A-Z` are uppercase characters  A through Z, `\d` are any digit characters (same as 0-9), and that's pretty much it aside from the literal `-` and ` ` (space not the same as `\s`). Effectively the same as the arrays you wrote.